# At what interval does the processor compare processes and their burst times in SRTF algorithm?

Tags: process, operating-system, job-scheduling

I'm studying OS and have been learning about scheduling algorithms. I was going through the Shortest Remaining Time First (SRTF) algorithm (preempted version of SJF) and had a small doubt. Most of the examples are able to explain the process in which the allocation and preemption takes place and I've got that part. But I haven't been able to figure out that at what interval does the processor ACTUALLY check/compare the processes. Like in reality. Is it every second? If yes, wouldn't it be highly inefficient? Kindly help me get this concept straight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a good question. You're actually hitting on a major pain point that a lot of recent research in operating systems explores.

As you said, if the algorithm does the check every second, the algorithm would not be very effective. If the algorithm checks too frequently (e.g., every few microseconds), the algorithm may waste a lot of time doing checks when that time could instead be used to run processes.

For standard kernel schedulers (e.g., Linux CFS), the checks usually occur at these two points:

1. Whenever a running process yields, blocks, dies, etc., which causes the scheduler to be invoked.
2. Whenever a timer interrupt is received. The time period is configurable, but people usually set the period to a few milliseconds.

A kernel that implements the SRTF algorithm would probably check at those points, too.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I was guessing something like this would be the case otherwise the OS wouldn't be efficient at all. But thanks again, this made it clear. 

Comment: What about when an I/O completion interrupt occurs?

Comment: @MartinJames Yes, there are a variety of places.